# Android permission in debug

Tags: android, maven, build, android-permissions

Some time ago I was added to my application network connectivity check. I forgotten to add **ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE** permission. When I run my application in debug state it works as expected but when I build my application as release(locally in maven). And I tried to run apk, it is crashed (because of missing permission). 
So my question is: **why android does not check permission in debug?**

Comment: you have to decide which all permission u need to use  in the app.

Comment: Perhaps you did not run your app through the code path that uses `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` with your debug testing.

Comment: I don't think that Android doesn't check permission in debug mode... But permissions are shared between apps that have the same sharedUserId (and also the same certificate = debug certificate).. Maybe you have an other app installed on your device with the same sharedUserId that defines this permission ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tested connection to internet so I used this permission to my tests(in debug state).